# How to get properties from an object without initializing or constructing the object

Tags: c#, interface

It don't sound like something that should be possible, but I'd like to ask prior to writing it off.

I am writing an app with a plugin system, I would like to get the properties contained inside the plugin class prior to initializing or constructing it

Interface:

```
public interface IMPlugin
{
    string PluginName { get; }
    string PluginSafeName { get; }
    string PluginDescription { get; }
    Version PluginVersion { get; }
    string PluginAuthorName { get; }

    [DefaultValue(null)]
    string PluginAuthorEmail { get; }

    [DefaultValue(null)]
    string PluginAuthorURL { get; }

    [DefaultValue(false)]
    bool PluginActive { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Plugin ID issued by InputMapper. Used for updates. </summary>
    int PluginID { get; }
}
```

Plugin:

```
   public class InputMonitor : IMPlugin,ApplicationPlugin
    {
        public string PluginName { get { return "My Plugin"; } }
        public string PluginSafeName { get { return "MyPlugin"; } }
        public string PluginDescription { get { return "My Plugin."; } }
        public Version PluginVersion { get { return new Version("0.1.0.0"); } }
        public string PluginAuthorName { get { return "John Doe"; } }
        public string PluginAuthorEmail { get { return "foo@bar.com"; } }
        public string PluginAuthorURL { get { return ""; } }
        public int PluginID { get { return 0; } }

        public bool PluginActive { get; set; }

        public InputMonitor()
        {

        }
    }
```

My issue is I want my application to be able to retrieve the plugin info prior to initializing it so users can activate and deactivate plugins at will but the details of the plugin still be visible in a plugin browser. But I don't want to have to rely on the plugin developers to not do anything in their constructor and only put their code in other interfaced methods.

Can a object be initialized and forcibly have its constructor ignored, or is there something to disallow constructors all together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your plugins should be configured via [*attributes*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw) rather than via exposing properties:

```
[Plugin(Name = "My Plugin", SafeName = "MyPlugin" ...)]
public class InputMonitor
```

You can access the attributes via reflection without creating an instance of the class.

After all, this is metadata about the type - not information about any one instance of the type.

Comment: Interesting, can these attributes be defined in the interface to force developers to add them to their plugins?

Comment: @Wobbles: No, you'd probably use them *instead* of the interface for the most part. (I can see how you might still want PluginActive as a per-instance property, but I'd probably achieve that via composition instead, unless each plugin would really have its own implementation). You can't force every use of an interface to also have an attribute (or vice versa) but it would be easy to detect types that *didn't* obey that and give a suitable error.

Comment: I'm starting to catch on, i'm new to interfaces. So the metadata can be retrieved from the type directly and not an instance of the type correct?

Comment: @Wobbles: Yes, exactly. See `Type.GetCustomAttributes`. (Read the link in my answer...)

Comment: Sounds like exactly what I was looking for, and being able to define attributes as a class makes it easy to check for completeness. This looks like it will open a lot of possibilities up to me, learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing a class and calling its constructor is the same thing.

Either you construct an instance of your plugin class just to read its properties and throw it away afterwards.

Or

You have a second helper/describer class. (which I understood you don't want)